# Dictionary of structs in a struct

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I'm new to Swift coming from a php environment.  I'm trying to recreate a multidimensional array to no avail.  Basically I'm stumped while attempting to create a dictionary within a struct.
This is the offending code at it's simplest:

```
struct Thing{
    let title: String
}

struct Thingy{
   let things = [String:Thing]()
   things["thing1"] = Thing(title:"stuff")
   things["thing2"] = Thing(title:"more stuff")
}
```

Any help in explaining why this isn't working are much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) and [Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

Comment: `let things: [String: Thing] = ["thing1": .init(title: "stuff"), "thing2": .init(title: "more stuff")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things going on here. For starters, you are initialising an empty Dict not an empty Array of dictionaries. Your property within your Thingy is a let which is a constant. Like mentioned earlier adding to things needs to be in a function inside a Struct and if you are changing that property you are mutating it.

```
struct Thing{
    let title: String
}

struct Thingy {

    var things = [[String:Thing]]()
    
    mutating func createSomeThings() {
        let thingo =  ["thing1" : Thing(title:"stuff")]
        things.append(thingo)
    }
    
    mutating func addAnotherThingWith(name: String, title: String) {
        let thingo =  [name : Thing(title:title)]
        things.append(thingo)
    }
    
}
```

There are to ways you can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a `let` dictionary, and code needs to be in a function.